# Exploring properties of groups in R

Tags: categorical-data, proportion, exploratory-data-analysis, r

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
  age gender             region homeowner.status extrovert agreeable conscientious type
1  34 Female   Northern England        Mortgaged         7         4             5    3
2  38 Female South East England        Mortgaged         4         3             6    1
3  35 Female   Northern England        Mortgaged         3         7             7    4
4  30 Female   Northern England        Mortgaged         2         6             5    3
5  60   Male           Scotland   Owned outright         4         5             6    4
6  66   Male   Northern England   Owned outright         7         6             6    3
```

The `type` column has been created by assigning each row to a cluster. The clusters were determined using variables that are not present in this frame. I would like to produce a general report on how the various types differ from each other in terms of the other columns.

That is, I would like to generate statistics of the form:

```
type 1.  5% less likely to be a homeowner (p=.003)
         3% more likely to be from Scotland (p=.03)
         2.1 pts more extrovert than the average (p=.xxxx)
```

I actually have many more columns than this, so a programmatic method of tackling each column is desirable. I am using R.

Comment: Your example appears to be a collection of results of hypothesis tests, but the nature of those tests is not apparent.  For instance, "less likely to be a homeowner" compared to what? What tests are you planning specifically? Are the columns not shown similarly discrete ordinal factors like those that are shown, or could they have various data types?  Please update your question to clarify and focus it.

Comment: Although couched in terms of R, this isn't much of a programming question, & there are statistical issues hidden just below the surface. I think this question is sufficiently on-topic for CV, & would be a better fit here than SO. (@whuber's questions do merit clarification, though.)

Comment: @gung Agreed. The problem I anticipate is that there may be *too many* statistical questions here, ranging from how to conduct hypothesis tests with various kinds of variables, whether to do that at all for exploration or summary, whether or how to correct for multiple tests, and more. That is why I encourage you, Joe, to clarify and focus this question lest it be so broad as to be unmanageable! You can always ask followup questions, so there's no need to address everything in one go.

Comment: I think I have been too general in this question. What I was after was full frame descriptive statistics grouped by a single column. E.g, chi square on factors, tests for normality then anova / Kruskal–Wallis etc on numerics. I can't quite figure out how to close the question on here but I am going to attempt rolling my own. I will be back with any stumbling blocks that I hit! Thanks @whuber

Comment: I don't think you can close your own question, but you can delete it if you want. I also think you may still get a useful answer, if you can clarify some of the mentioned points.